# Using ANT I want to copy modified and unmodified files

Tags: java, ant, copy

I want to copy modified and unmodified files to a directory along with the parent directory among a number of directories using ant. when i am using modified task, it copies only modified files along with parent directory. Unmodified files not copied.please help

Answer (score 2):

You can use `copy` task with `overwrite` option enabled. Option `overwrite` will overwrite existing files even if the destination files are newer. For example:

```
<copy todir="dest" overwrite="true">
    <fileset dir="src" />
</copy>
```

Reference: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html